# SQL: Use Day or Week in DIFFDATE function?

Tags: sql

Should a programmer use day or week when using the diffdate function? It seems to me that they would work generally the same. One would simply use whichever one fit better for their needs. However from this query, DIFFDATE seems to have gotten different results even though the dates are very similar. (Especially row 3 and 8) I do not understand why row 3 would get 8 days but only one week and row 8 would also get 8 rows but only 1 week.

```
SELECT OrderDate, ShipDate, DateDiff(week, OrderDate, ShipDate)as week, DateDiff(day, OrderDate,      ShipDate) as day
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
Where DateDiff(day, OrderDate, ShipDate) > 7
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server's `datediff()` function probably doesn't do what you think it does.

It counts the number of boundaries that are passed between two datetimes.  So, `datediff(day)` between 2014-01-01 23:59 and 2014-01-02 00:01 is 1 day.  `datediff(day)` for 2014-01-01 00:01 and 2014-01-01 23:59 is 0 days.

The same applies to weeks.

This is the behavior you are seeing.  It is well documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for replying to my post @GordonLinoff. Your explanation makes helps and I'm reading through the link. Perhaps you could clarify why there would be a different week number on row 3 and row 8 - since both OrderDate days are the 31 and their ShipDates are the 8th. Does the SQL week begin on Sunday? Or is it a set of 7 days and doesn't matter what day of the week it starts on?

Comment: @user3281388 . . . When weeks start depends on `DATEFIRST` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).  The default is that the week starts on Monday.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Monday, 1st to Tuesday, 9th is one week (you moved into the following week), but Sunday, 7th to Monday, 15th is two weeks (you skipped a whole week, and my weeks start on Mondays).

This is just like moving one hour from 22:00 to 23:00 is 0 days difference, but moving from 23:45 to 0:45 is 1 day difference.

Or (for years) moving from Dec, 30th to Dec, 31st versus Dec, 31st to January, 1st.

Comment: Thanks @Thilo for your reply. Does SQL follow a normal calendar week? Or is it a set of 7 days and it doesn't matter what day it starts on?